# Node creation using rules with AJAX?

Tags: 7, nodes, rules, ajax, entities

Im am using [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to create a node entity when the user saves a status from the [statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module. The Status message is copied into the title of the new node and then this title is shown in my view. I'm doing this as I need to have the Status message as an entity and this is the only way I could fathom - I'm aware this is probably considered a bit of a hack by most, but its ok for me up to this point.

My question is would it be possible to have this node show up in my view when it is created by rules without having to reload the page? I am not a developer but I can get by with PHP and JS. A small amount of research has led me to AJAX and JQuerey as a solution, but Im wondering if anyone knows if there's anything else out there (such as a module) which may help me achieve the right solution without too much heavy programming?